# Using @ to specify email in Scala form

Tags: scala, playframework

My Play Scala view form has the next cmd:

```
<p>Please, contact support at: <a href="mailto:jzsupp@comp.usa">Joe Doe</a> </p>
```

Yet I get the error:

```
not found: value comp
```

Is there anyway to escape the @ symbol to use just for email address?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@` is a special syntax, so you need to escape it by adding another `@`

```
<p>Please, contact support at: <a href="mailto:jzsupp@@comp.usa">Joe Doe</a> </p>
```

For reference: [Syntax: the magic ‘@’ character](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaTemplates#Syntax:-the-magic-%E2%80%98@%E2%80%99-character)